# Nested delay in Javascript for loop

Tags: javascript

I am attempting to program a task where respondents must be able to differentiate between different categories. A specific example would be to show respondents several photos, and them ask them to identify all the photos which match a certain description by clicking the space bar.

I have 8 "blocks", or in other terms 8 different categories of photos. (say, block 1 = people wearing hats, block 2 = people with glasses, etc.). In each block I show the respondent 20 photos, and ask them to identify all the photos matching the category of the block.

The difficult part is that in this task I need to have the photos delayed by a certain amount. Specifically, before the beginning of each block (i.e. before the first photo in each block is shown), I would like to show a blank photo for 2 seconds. Then the block begins. Then between each photo, I will have a 1 second interval where I show the blank photo. And I would like to display each photo for 1 second as well. So within a block, this procedure would go:

1) photo for 1 second
2) 1 second blank photo
3) 2nd photo for 1 second
4) 1 second blank photo

etc. I would do this for 20 photos in each block. I am having some difficulty in implementing the interval between photos, as well as getting the interval of displaying the photos to run correctly. Similar code to what I am using is below:

```
var total = 0;
var i = 0; // block counter
var locBlank = '.blankPhoto.jpg';
var stimulusInterval = 1000;
var totalTime = stimulusInterval * 20;
var interStimulusInterval = 1500;
var j = -1; // counter within block
function outer(){
    if (i++ < 8){
        block = blocks[i];
        blockPhotos = ... // code to get block photos
        var loc;
        inner();
        j = -1;
    }
    total += totalTime;
    totalTime *= 2; // new
    setTimeout(outer, total);
}

function inner(){
    if(j++ < 20){
        loc = blockPhotos[j];
        show_image(loc); // change image, then push results later
            // code to record response here...
    }
    if(j < 20){
        setTimeout(inner, stimulusInterval);
    }
}
```

As you can see have tried to do this using recursive functions, which I got the idea from by browsing similar SO questions. This code also does not implement an interval between photos which I also need to do. This code accomplishes what I want to for the first block, but does not work properly after that block. By that I mean in the second block, the time between photos is cut approximately in half, and then no other photos are shown after the second block. I had originally tried to use setTimeout in a nested for loop with a similar approach but that did not work either.

I am looking for solutions on how to implement all of these delays.

Comment: Do you have a jsfiddle showing a working version of what you've done so far?

Comment: How critical is the timing -- can it be "1 second-ish"?

Comment: It's not something that I can post on jsfiddle because the photos are stored locally on my computer, and I can't post them on the internet.

Comment: If by 1 second ish, you mean 1 second += a few milliseconds, then that's fine. .8 - 1.2 seconds is probably a fine range actually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not recommend recursion for this scenario, it's just a simple iteration task. Something like this would do the job, use your own imagination for what happens in the first part of the `DoAction` method, and what data you need in the `actions` array.

```
var actions =
[
    { "action": "Photo 1", "duration": "2000" },
    { "action": "Photo 2", "duration": "2000" },
    { "action": "Blank", "duration": "1000" },
    { "action": "Photo 3", "duration": "2000" },
    { "action": "Photo 4", "duration": "2000" },
];

var actionIndex = 0;

function DoAction(){
    $("#actionContainer").text(actions[actionIndex].action);
    var delay = actions[actionIndex].duration;
    actionIndex++;
    if (actionIndex < actions.length)
    {
        setTimeout(DoAction, delay);
    }
}

DoAction();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/r4yRV/

Comment: How is that not recursion?

Comment: It's re-entering the method from a callback, not directly from the method. The stack depth will not increase.